# Create button with image programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In XAML it's easy to define a button with an image:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSound"
        Click="SoundButton"
        Height="40"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0">
    <Image x:Name="speakerImg" Source="/png/btn_speak_i.png" />
</Button>
```

I want to do that in `c#`:

```
// Prepare two BitmapImages
BitmapImage SoundDisable = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///png/btn_speak_i.png", 
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
BitmapImage SoundEnable = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///png/btn_speak.png", 
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

// Define and Load Button
btnSound = new Button();
btnSound.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
btnSound.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
Thickness margin = new Thickness(0,00,20,0);
btnSound.Margin = margin;
btnSound.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnSound_Click);
btnSound.IsEnabled = false;
topBar.Children.Add(btnSound);
```

I can find no way to add an image to the button. Something like

```
btnSound.Content = SoundDisable;
```

Is not working. It shows only a text with the type of the image inside the button. In the XAML version, I set the Image with

```
speakerImg.Source = SoundDisable;
```

because the image is defined with an `x:Name`.

How can I programmatically add a named image to my button?

Comment: you can take one stackpanel instead of button and add image and button respectively add in that and handle mousebuttondown of stackpanel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: add an `Image`, and set the image `Source` as your `BitmapImage`.

```
// Prepare two BitmapImages
BitmapImage SoundDisable = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///png/btn_speak_i.png", 
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
BitmapImage SoundEnable = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///png/btn_speak.png", 
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

// Define and Load Button
btnSound = new Button();
btnSound.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
btnSound.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
Thickness margin = new Thickness(0,00,20,0);
btnSound.Margin = margin;
btnSound.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnSound_Click);
btnSound.IsEnabled = false;

var image = new Image();
image.Source = SoundDisable;
btnSound.Content = image;

topBar.Children.Add(btnSound);
```

To change the image:

```
((Image)btnSound.Content).Source = SoundEnable;
```

Comment: @yasen It is a matter of personal preference. I prefer reading `as` instead of a cast. As long as I know for certain it is an `Image` I use `as`. When I don't know for sure I can use a cast and catch (when needed) a `InvalidCastOperation`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? When you know it's an Image, use a cast, to enforce it and get an exception if for some unexpected reason it's not. When you don't know (and it's acceptable to be something else) use `as` and test if it's not null. At least that's how I know it. :)